# Incorrect x8086 assembly language

Tags: assembly

I have a question about the following data segment:

```
data segment
s dw 7,5,2
x db $
....
data ends.
```

I have to know what is the value of x.I have found in a book that is 6 but I don't know why.
And if I have instead db, dw what is now the value of x?

Comment: Do you know what `dw` actually means? (If not, you need to revise your lecture notes.)

Comment: Yes,I know.It means word

Comment: .. And so the word `word`, in this case, means *how many bytes*? (Sorry to drag it out of you.)

Comment: well,I don't write anywhere how many bytes.I ve just said what is the value of x.Where am I wrong?

Comment: This data segment I found it in a book.So it is a mistake x db $ and it should have been x dw $?

Comment: It doesn't actually matter in this particular instance what the type of x is. The question asks what is (the offset of) x? Since you define 3 words (7, 5, and 2) before it, and since the data segment starts at zero, that puts x at position 6.

Comment: Ok,the 0 position is data segment.And the first position is 2? and this is what I don t get.How x is position 6? If we count from left to right from 2 it comes 2 it 1,5-position 2 and 7-position 3.Why 6?

Comment: First, the symbol `$` (in this context) means approximately "here" - the offset into the data segment. If `s` had been three bytes, `x` would be 3. If `s` had been three dwords, `x` would be 12. But `s` is three words, so `x` is... ?

Comment: 6.Thanks finally I get it.So x can be either defined as db or dw,the answer remains 6.

Answer (score 0):

`dw` is the assembler directive for `define word`.  Now the length of a word may differ by machine, but in this case it is 2 bytes.  You are storing three of these words (7, 5, and 2), so they will take up 6 bytes.

`db` is the assembler directive for `define byte`, and `$` means the current offset.  As you are at offset 6 where this command appears, `x` is given the value 6.

Using `db` to store the current offset is quite likely to be dangerous, since it will not give the right answer if it is at an offset greater than 255, which it easily could be if you extend your program and add data. `dw` should be okay for 8086 (I cannot recall right now, but I think offsets are limited to 16 bits).

Comment: I don t get the part with "the length of a word (..) but in this case it is 2 bytes.Why do we know it is 2 bytes?From where?

Comment: Have a look at [this Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)).  In the [table of word sizes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)#Table_of_word_sizes) you can see the Intel 8086 (in 1978) has a word size of 16 bits, or 2 bytes.